# Unable to register Microsoft Logger with Unity

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, .net-framework-version

I have a Worker with logger and the project is throwing an error:
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Test.IWorker", name = "(none)"

```cs
public class SimpleWorker : IWorker
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public SimpleWorker(

        ILogger<SimpleWorker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

I am using Unity 4.0.0 version and .NET 4.8.

So far, I have tried with solution that I found on StackOverflow, but unsucesfully:

```cs
_container = new UnityContainer();
var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
var factoryMethod =
    typeof(LoggerFactoryExtensions).
        GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .First(x => x.ContainsGenericParameters);

_container.RegisterType(typeof(ILogger<>), new InjectionFactory((c, t, s) =>
{
    var genFactoryMethod =
        factoryMethod.MakeGenericMethod(t.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
    return genFactoryMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { loggerFactory });
}));
```

Also, I tried direct injection with, but it didn't work:

```cs
_container = new UnityContainer();
_container.RegisterType<ILogger<SimpleWorker>>();
```

edit:
Now I have other issue with logger factory:

```
    var factory = new LoggerFactory();
    factory.AddLog4Net("log4net.config");
    container.RegisterInstance<ILoggerFactory>(factory);
    container.RegisterType(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
```

Then:

```
foreach (var item in _unityContainer.Registrations)
            {
                var named = _unityContainer.ResolveAll(item.RegisteredType);
                if (_unityContainer.IsRegistered(item.RegisteredType))
                {
                    var tmp = _unityContainer.Resolve(item.RegisteredType);
                }
            }
```

Above code throws error: Resolving Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[TCategoryName][],(none)
---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not execute the method because either the method itself or the containing type is not fully instantiated.

Comment: The error complains about `IWorker`, not `ILogger`. Your code never registers any `IWorker` implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking it. You just have to register the `LoggerFactory` and the `Logger<T>` implementation:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Unity;
using Unity.Lifetime;

var container = new UnityContainer();

var factory = new LoggerFactory();
container.RegisterInstance<ILoggerFactory>(factory,
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

container.RegisterType(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>),
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

container.RegisterType<IWorker, SimpleWorker>();

var worker = container.Resolve<IWorker>();

public interface IWorker { }
public class SimpleWorker : IWorker
{
    private ILogger<SimpleWorker> _logger;
    public SimpleWorker(ILogger<SimpleWorker> logger) => _logger = logger;
}
```

Also note that there is a [Unity.Microsoft.Logging](https://github.com/unitycontainer/microsoft-logging) NuGet package that allows you to achieve the same:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Unity;
using Unity.Microsoft.Logging;

var container = new UnityContainer();

var factory = new LoggerFactory();

container.AddExtension(new LoggingExtension(factory));

container.RegisterType<IWorker, SimpleWorker>();

var worker = container.Resolve<IWorker>();
```

Comment: I tried, but the exception is same.

Comment: The error complains about `IWorker`, not `ILogger`. The `SimpleWorker` class wasn't registered

Comment: I have             _container.RegisterType<IWorker, SimpleWorker>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());   And error is: 'Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Test.IWorker", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?                 This worked before I added logging, so yes, I registered SimpleWorker

Comment: I updated my answer to include a compiling and fully working example. You can copy paste this code into an empty console project. Just add the `Unity` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` NuGet packages.

Comment: I don't have exceptions anymore, however, nothing is logging, file is empty, and also console doesn't show messages,  I added config in App.config and                var logRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
         XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));

Comment: You will have to set up your `LoggerFactory` in order to enable logging. By default `LoggerFactory` is empty; you will have to add logging providers to enable actual logging. To understand how Microsoft's logging infrastructure works, take a look at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line).

Comment: @Steven I still have some issues with resolving, even with logger factory. I edited post

Comment: @pakerinjo: As I understand your update correctly, you are now trying to validate your Unity configuration. This seems unrelated to your initial question, and something I don't have the answer to. You might want to post a new question here on StackOverflow.